# Use of the lennard-jones equation

Tags: python

As part of an assignment I have been tasked with creating the lennard-jones equation which I have found the lennard-jonaes equation at this site https://www.jonathangross.de/files/IPCS2015/Lennard-Jones%20plot.pdf.

I now need to do the following:

1. Pass R as the input argument to the function LJpotential.
2. Pass the output of the function to the variable V.

Can you please advise me how to approach this part of the programming?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? What have you tried? This is way too broad.

Comment: I would like to be able to write the lennard jones equation and have it plot a graph.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to control the workflow between R and python?

U may have a shell file to run the R and store the output into a txt or csv file. After that, you can use python to do other things with it.